# Can't get ECC error reporting to work in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, hardware

I've been trying unsuccessfully to get ECC error reporting to work in Debian 11. The hardware configuration is as follows:

- MB: ASRock X570 Pro4
- CPU: Ryzen 7 PRO 5750G
- RAM: Kingston KSM26ED8/32ME (x2)

All of these support ECC, and ECC is also enabled in the UEFI settings.

Here are some commands I've tried:

```
# dmesg | grep -i edac
[    0.331589] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0

# edac-util --status
edac-util: EDAC drivers loaded. No memory controllers found

# lsmod | grep edac
edac_mce_amd           32768  0

# ls /sys/devices/system/edac/mc
power  subsystem  uevent

# modprobe amd64_edac_mod 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'amd64_edac_mod': No such device

# modprobe amd64_edac_mod ecc_enable_override=1
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'amd64_edac_mod': No such device

# ras-mc-ctl --status
ras-mc-ctl: drivers not loaded.
```

Is there anything else I could try?

**Edit**

The kernel patch that @sup refers to fixes the problem: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=0b8bf9cb142da59a14622bba168ebcd6d0a54499

It was included in the mainline kernel from version 5.17-rc1.

Comment: Please check if kernel patch mentioned here helps https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/rjlhzs/psa_linux_ecc_currently_broken_on_amd_5750g_patch/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I compiled kernel version 5.17-rc5, which contains the patch, and now ECC reporting works.